# Java to C++ converting

Tags: java, c++, arrays

In Java, we sometimes do this:

`int [] foo = new int [5]`

How do you do this in C++? I've put this in and it gave me an error.

Comment: There are many ways. For example `std:array<int, 5> foo;`

Comment: Of course it gave an error, they're different languages. If you're going to ask this style of question repeatedly, you should invest in a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/395760). Or just hone your ability to search the internet...

Comment: @user3554687: if you like one of the answers, could you accept it by clicking on a tick next to the score of the answer - it should become green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
int foo[5];
```

or

```
int *foo = new int[5];
...
delete []foo; // remember to release its memory afterwards!!!
```

or

```
#include <vector>
...
std::vector<int> foo(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<int> foo(5);
```

Don't use int[], this is ok if the size of your array is fixed (you do not need new, just

```
int a[5];
```

), but if it is variable, than it is a pain because you need to remember to disallocate it.

Comment: I suggest std::vector instead of "naked" pointers because user3554687 needs to leart to use std library, it will greatly benefit him. Naked pointers require disallocation, if the size of the array is not fixed (which is generally the case). This is more C than C++.

Answer (score 2):

```
int *foo = new int[5];
```

This is how it is done without using any library, but you will have to manually delete that memory after you are done with it or else you have a memory leak

It is not recommended that you do it that way thought. You should use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if the size of the array will not change during its life time. If you want an array that can dynamic grow than you should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: there is no need for 'new' if the size is fixed, just int a[5]; will do.

Comment: @YuliaV That doesn't exactly have the same effect as its Java counter part